# Regex for containing x AND not containing y without lookarounds

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a simple regex for a string that contains a dot (.) AND doesn't contain @.

I managed to do this like this:

```
(^(?!.*@).*\..*$)
```

and it works!
But I'm getting an error:

```
'Value "/(^(?!.*@).*\..*$)" must be a valid regular expression. Details: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax.'
```

I've searched and found out that the issue is with the negation part - "?!".
Trying to change the expression to work with ^ but with no luck.

Would appriciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Try `^[^@.]*[.][^@]*$`

Comment: How can it be working if you're getting an error?

Comment: @Barmar what I meant by that is that the Regex itself is correct but our system doesn't support it's syntax

Comment: What is "your system"? The question is tagged `javascript` and `perl`, both of them should support this.

Comment: @Barmar The error said "invalid or unsupported Perl syntax". The info I've given in the question is what I know, and the answer I got from Wiktor is what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: What that means is that it's perl syntax that isn't supported by your regular expression library. You should tag the question with the language you're using.

Comment: @Barmar this is the first time I've posted a question so I wasn't aware of how the tags should work. Anyway someone removed already the irrelevant tags :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex that does not rely on lookarounds:

```
^[^@.]*\.[^@]*$
```

Or, if you have trouble with finding the right amount of escaping backslashes:

```
^[^@.]*[.][^@]*$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^@.]*` - zero or more chars other than a `.` and `@`
- `\.` / `[.]` - a mere dot char
- `[^@]*` - zero or more chars other than a `@` char
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Why do you need `[^@.]*` instead of `[^@]*`?

Comment: @Barmar To reduce backtracking.